# Infinite series $\frac1{1+\ln x}+\frac2{1+(\ln x)^2}+\frac4{1+(\ln x)^4}+\frac8{1+(\ln x)^8}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Evaluate the following expression $(x>e)$
$$\frac1{1+\ln x}+\frac2{1+(\ln x)^2}+\frac4{1+(\ln x)^4}+\frac8{1+(\ln x)^8}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ln x=y, x>e\iff y=\ln x>1$

Now use repeatedly $$\dfrac1{1+u}+\dfrac1{1-u}=\dfrac2{1-u^2}$$ to get the partial sum

$$\dfrac{2^n}{1-y^{(2^n)}}-\dfrac1{1-y}$$

Now set $2^n=r$ and use $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\dfrac r{2^r}=0$$

Comment: @Dr.MV, What should it be, then?

Comment: Should the $n$'th partial sum be $$\frac{2^{n+1}}{1-y^{2^{n+1}}}$$This doesn't affect the development, but I just thought that it might be better to be precise.